# Next js with redux-saga problem when store.dispatch(END)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-saga

Hello guys my code is similar to this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-redux-saga.

However, when I try to do this code:

```
export const getStaticProps = wrapper.getStaticProps(async ({ store }) => {

  store.dispatch(initCategoriesRequest());

  store.dispatch(END);

  await store.sagaTask.toPromise();

});
```

It says:

```
Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

and it points to `store.dispatch(END)`.

Also, if i put `async (ctx)` instead of `async ({ store })`, I don't get any paramters (for example `req`, `res`, `params`, etc.) for `ctx`; there's only the store.

Maybe the problem is something with the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but you must import the END action from redux-saga.

e.g.

`import { END } from 'redux-saga';`